# Slow network speed in one direction only between two devices

Tags: home-networking, file-transfer

I have an odd situation which I can't find a reason for this behavior.

I've created this graphic for ease of explanation, but to be clear, the Desktop is connected via WiFi to the switch, Server and NAS are over wired ethernet:

[image]

My NAS runs RAID5 storage over several protocols. I've tested this with simple FTP and get the same results as SMB/CIFS/NFS.  All these results are via FTP.

The server run Ubuntu 14.04 and is connected to the same switch as the NAS.  Both the Server and NAS are connected to the switch via ethernet cables.  Server is 100Mbps, NAS is Gigabit.

The Desktop is connected to the switch via 5G WiFi running Ubuntu 16.04 (But I get the same behavior in Windows).  In all situations in the graphic above with green arrows, I get between 10-12 MB/s speeds.  Going from server to NAS, there are momentary drops to 0, which I assume is the NAS doing its work for the RAID5 writes.

The problem lies with going from Desktop to NAS, I only get 600-900 KB/s (Not even 1MB/s!).  And it is *only* from Desktop TO NAS.  Downloading from NAS to Desktop is the usual 10-12 MB/s.

What could cause this problem between only two devices and only in *one* direction?  At the speed from Desktop to NAS, it's honestly much faster to upload to the Server first, and then transfer from the Server to the NAS, but it requires several extra steps to accomplish.

**EDIT:** **Update** On the NAS, I disabled jumbo frames, which should not cause an issue since the files I transfer are over 1 GB.  But this improved the transfer from Desktop to NAS from 900 KB/s to 3 MB/s.  But, this 3 MB/s is still only 1/3 to 1/4 the speed of all other possible transfers (green arrows).

Comment: This is most likely a WIFI congestion / signal strength issue, which your server is negotiating by dropping to 0 and then going full tilt, while your PC is slowing down for every drop (ie a different TCP congestion management algorythm)

Comment: @davidgo But from Desktop to Server over WiFi, I get full and constant 10+MB/s.  Server and NAS are connected to the same WiFi router over Ethernet.  NAS even has gigabit while server only has 100 Mbps.  Server to NAS is over ethernet and only drops because of RAID5 write bottleneck, but it only drops for maybe half a second, resumes at 10+MB/s for several seconds and repeats.

Comment: @davidgo Perhaps the diagram wasn't clear, but the desktop's WiFi is connected to the switch, not directly to the server or NAS.